# Reading Hibernate configurations dynamically

Tags: java, hibernate, amazon-kms

I need to fetch hibernate connection url, username and password configurations from another service AMS (just like amazon KMS).

I have written another method to fetch those values from AMS. BUT how to set/use these values hibernate to connect my database.

eg. hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
```

Util.java

```
getAMSValue(propertyName){
...
}
```

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you specify complete configuration in a java file instead of XML?

See this [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic)

> A org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration also allows you to specify
>   configuration properties.
>
> ... ...
>
> This is not the only way to pass configuration properties to
>   Hibernate. Some alternative options include:
>
> 1. Pass an instance of java.util.Properties to Configuration.setProperties().
> 2. Place a file named hibernate.properties in a root directory of the classpath.
> 3. Set System properties using java -Dproperty=value.
> 4. Include  elements in hibernate.cfg.xml (this is discussed later).

---

In your case, you can configure somewhat like this in your java file

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();

...
...
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", getAMSValue("url"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", getAMSValue("username"));
configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", getAMSValue("password"));
```